# Stripe connect error in creating account

Tags: java, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am not able to create account of a customer in my application. The code which I found on stripe documentation id:

```
Map<String, Object> accountParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
accountParams.put("email", "example@mywyzer.com");
accountParams.put("country", "US");
accountParams.put("type", "custom");
Account account = Account.create(accountParams);
```

When I run this it gives the this error:

> "You can only create new accounts if you've registered your platform"

I'm not able to create account.

Can anyone tell me the whole flow of using stripe?

I might not be following that flow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your platform by going to Connect --> Settings.

Answer (score 0):

That code is for creating a managed Stripe account as part of [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/), which I suspect is not what you are trying to do.

If you are only interested in charging a customer, you do not need to create a Stripe account for them, only a customer object. You would use Stripe Elements or Checkout to collect the customer's payment details and create a token, pass this token to your backend, and then create a customer using that token, as described in the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

```
Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
customerParams.put("description", "Customer for elizabeth.williams@example.com");
customerParams.put("source", "tok_visa");
// ^ obtained with Stripe.js
Customer.create(customerParams);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer

Comment: i dont have problem with Customer.create(customerParam). I have problem with Account.create(accountParam). I am working on a SAAS model application where user have to subscribe a business plan in order to use application.

Comment: @AhsanSharif ok, so are you actually using Stripe Connect?

Comment: In that case, you need to register your Stripe account as a platform as documented at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart#register-platform